# Can't install Windows on a second partition due to the disk format being GPT, what's going on?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I want to have 2 Windows 10 installations side by side, so I shrunk my current installation to make space for the second one. I have a hard drive of 1.2TB and currently it has 3 partitions:

- 100MB EFI System Partition.
- 292GB Windows 10 C: NTFS partition
- 824GB Unallocated
- 500MB Recovery partition

[image]

When I try to install on the unallocated space, whether I leave it unallocated or I create an NTFS partition, I get the same error:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

[image]

Any ideas what's going on? Why can't I install on a GPT hard drive?

Comment: the 100 MB EFI partition might be too small to be updated.

Comment: @LPChip how do I confirm that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Don't know, but now that you added the screenshots, I doubt this is the case. The boot partition is your C drive, so that one is affected, and all is set to GPT. not sure about this one.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem here... You misread the error. it says the disk IS GPT, and that is not allowed. Windows wants to be installed on MBR apparently.

Comment: @LPChip wow, you are right... I'm so confused now.

Comment: I have now updated the whole question to match the problem I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved this but I'm not 100% sure about my solution. When booting from the USB install media, the BIOS boot menu had many options. When I went into the boot configuration and changed CSM compatibility from enabled to auto, which apparently controls GPT vs legacy booting for various different sources (SATA, PCI, network, USB), and rebooted, the boot menu had way fewer options. It actually only had two: my current Windows 10 install and USB. I selected USB and it worked.

My hypothesis is that I was booting from my USB install media in legacy instead of GPT mode and that when I disabled everything but GPT, I booted in GPT. I bet I could have just selected another of the many options I had to boot USB in GPT mode instead of legacy mode, without having to change the BIOS setting, but that didn't occur to me.

This video inspired me to try that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agV0RbIS2bk

Comment: I was about to post an answer with the same observation. For GPT installs, you need to have secure boot enabled (UEFI boot), aka legacy disabled. See here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025535/memory-and-storage.html

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs. With Windows gpt is required for UEFI boot and MBR is required for BIOS boot. If drive is blank, it will just install. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. The BIOS mode was allowed for older hardware. Some vendors now are only have UEFI class 3 systems, which is they do not even have the BIOS/CSM/Legacy option.